# "CircleCI received exit code 1" after Jest tests are successfully executed

Tags: jestjs, circleci

I have some API tests which are 100% passed. The results are reported in Testrail using a custom `testResultsProcessor` where I make the calls(async) to testrail.

Everything works fine, testrail run and results are successfully created and updated, but the CircleCI fails with this error:

```
Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

Any thoughts on this?